# Posting to a Facebook Page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm working on a [PAC-style website](http://elections2015.no2bio.org), where we try to have the users contact parliament members. We currently have Facebook integration using the share dialog, but I'm not able to have the generated posts mention the parliament members.
Is there any way of doing this? I've looked at quite a few options so far, but it seems that all of them require the PMs to be either friends of the FB user, or the FB user to like the PM page.

Any guidance will be very appreciated. Other suggestions are welcomed as well.

-- Michael

ps the code for the site is available here: https://github.com/no2bio/elections2015

Comment: If the users want to mention someone or a page, they have to do that themselves – your app is not allowed to “chose” that for them.

Answer (score 0):

As @CBroe mentioned, seems like FB blocked this option (see, e.g. [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.2#pages)). We ended up linking to the PM page, so that the users can post directly there.